# Can we include condition as an argument in custom functions?

Tags: php, arrays, function, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a multidimensional array

```
$num1 = array(1, 4, 6, 12, 15, 16, 21, 34, 25, 29);
$num2 = array(1, 5, 18, 19, 23, 19, 23, 45, 23, 16);
$array = array($num1, $num2);
```

I want to extract all the values from $array where the $array[0] values meet some condition e.g. have a value between 10 & 20.

to get the required values from $array I can use this code:

```
$count = count($array[0]);
$new_array = array_fill(0, $count, array());
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
    if($array[0][$i] >= 10 && $array[0][$i] <= 20)
        {
        $new_array[0][] = $array[0][$i];
        $new_array[1][] = $array[1][$i];
        }
    }
//I get the array that I need
print_r($new_array);
```

This is the code I need to change every time

**$array[0][$i] >= 10 && $array[0][$i] <= 20** (condition --> values from the first sub array are >= 10 and <= 20)

result would be

```
Array(0 => Array(0 => 12, 1 => 15, 2 => 16), 1 => Array(0 => 19, 1 => 23, 2 => 19))
```

another condition

**$array[1][$i] >= 20 && $array[1][$i] <= 30** (condition --> values from the second sub array are >= 20 and <= 30)

result would be

```
Array(0 => Array(0 => 15, 1 => 21, 2 => 25), 1 => Array(0 => 23, 1 => 23, 2 => 23))
```

I need to do such operations with different columns using different conditions. So, instead of writing code for looping every time, I want to create a function with condition as an argument. Is it possible, if so how?

I would like to have a function with three arguments as shown below

```
function_name ($array, $column_num, $condition)
```

Any alternative solutions are also welcome.... :)

Code I used finally to get this done....

```
<?php
function mdarray_condition_extract($array, $column, $condition) 
    {
    $count = count($array[0]);
    $nsac = count($array);
    $new_array = array_fill(0, $nsac, array());
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
        $valToTest = $array[$column][$i];
        if ($condition($valToTest))
            {
            for($k = 0; $k < $nsac; $k++)
                {
                $new_array[$k][] = $array[$k][$i];
                }
            }
        }
    return $new_array;
    }

$array = array(array(1, 4, 6, 12, 15, 16), array(1, 5, 18, 19, 23, 19));
$columns = array(0,1,0);
$conditions =   [
                0 => function($val){return $val >= 10 && $val <= 20;},
                1 => function($val){return $val >= 20 && $val <= 30;},
                2 => function($val){return $val == 6 || $val == 20;}
                ];
$combo = array($columns, $conditions);
$condcount = count($combo[0]);
for($i = 0; $i < $condcount; $i++)
    {
    print_r(mdarray_condition_extract($array, $combo[0][$i], $combo[1][$i])); echo "<br><br>";
    }
?>
```

Thanks all for the response, it helped me in a great way...!!

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.. could you provide an example of a condition and an array set both matching and not matching?

Comment: have you tried [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass a _predicate_ function. Unfortunately, PHP does not support first-class functions, so you're stuck with [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: @r3mus I have edited and hope it's much clear now.

Comment: Getting there! Where in your example would you change something? Can you highlight the parts that need to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is very close.

```
function filterParallelArrays($array, $predicateFilterIndex, $predicate) 
{
    $count = count($array[0]);
    $new_array = array_fill(0, $count, array());
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $valToTest = $array[$predicateFilterIndex][$i];
        if ($predicate($valToTest))
        {
            $new_array[0][] = $array[0][$i];
            $new_array[1][] = $array[1][$i];
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}


$predicate = function($val)
{
    return $val >= 10 && $val <= 20;
};

print_r(filterParallelArrays($array, 0, $predicate));
```

Comment: This worked like magic. I got a line wrong previously, so changed that one
`$subarrcount = count($array);
$new_array = array_fill(0, $subarrcount, array());`

Answer (score 1):

You question is about *filtering* your arrays. For that, PHP has built-in function [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) . It takes callback for filtering values.

If I got your question correctly, you want to apply filter to your sub-arrays - and, probably, with different conditions. Normally, if do that statically, it is:

```
$array[0] = array_filter($array[0], function($x)
{
   return $x>=10 && $x<=20; //item between 10 and 20
});
```

-but if you have predefined list for each column, you can fill a map:

```
$conditions = [
   //column index => condition callback:
   0 => function($x){ return $x>=10 && $x<=20; },
   1 => function($x){ return $x==50 || $x==80; },
   //e t.c.
];

foreach($array as $key=>$column)
{
   if(array_key_exists($key, $conditions))
   {
      $array[$key] = array_filter($array[$key], $conditions[$key]);
   }
}
```

So, using `array_filter()` - you can do it natively, I think you won't need your own custom function to do this (because wrapping native function has little sense in this case).

Comment: my explanation gave you an impression that I am going to use similar kind of condition every time, but it's not so. I might use a condition to check if the value falls within a range or if it equals a value or if it contains a string. Also I can check the condition in any of the sub arrays.

Comment: Sorry guess I can give as many conditions I need in this code.

Comment: The solution you provided can be used only for a script. If I want to do a similar thing in another script I have to allover repeat this code there as well. Instead of it is there any possibility of creating a function based on this so that I can just call the function to get the result.

Comment: What prevents you from separating your conditions into single file and then include it when you need?

Comment: In my work I do this kind of operation very often, so I won't have the exclusive list of conditions in my hand. If I create a function, I can use it as and when needed without bothering about keeping them in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Given your latest update, you could do something like this. But I'm still not really sure what your objective is here, so this might be totally out to lunch.

```
function array_function($key, $lcond, $rcond)
{
    $count = count($array[0]);
    $new_array = array_fill(0, $count, array());
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if($array[$key][$i] >= $lcond && $array[$key][$i] <= $rcond)
        {
            $new_array[0][] = $array[0][$i];
            $new_array[1][] = $array[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    //I get the array that I need
    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: if it was the same type of condition that I am going to use again and again this is a valid solution. But, in my case I can use different kinds of conditions that too with any of the sub arrays.